# Subtract 20 month from user provided date in yymm in unix

Tags: shell, date, unix

```
oldest_year_month_temp=201602

NUM_PART_RETAIN=20

oldest_year_month=`date --date="$(oldest_year_month_temp +%Y%m) - $NUM_PART_RETAIN month" "+%Y%m"`
```

Date is not coming as expected.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to do it would be to simply append a `01` to your input of `yymm` to provide a format `date -d` could read as the starting date, then simply subtract `20` months and output the resulting date in `%y%m` format. For example, if you provide the date `9910` (Oct. 1999), you can do:

```
$ date -d "991001 - 20 months" +%y%m
9802
```

Which returns Feb. 1998 (20 months earlier)

(*note:* the `$` above just indicates a command by a normal user as opposed to `#` indicating a command by the super user (e.g. root))

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `$(...)` there must be a command, e.g. `$(date ...)`.

This should have been obvious from the error message you got, which was probably `oldest_year_month_temp: no such command`.

When reading from a variable, you must write a `$` before its name.

Comment: can you please provide the command i'm still facing the error